# translation of the Shulchan Aruch online

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, translation

I'm looking for a translation of the entire *shulchan aruch* online. Do you know of any website that might have one?

Comment: http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch

Comment: Why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think there is an entire translation (though maybe there's one on archive.org). There is a good WIP on sefaria though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [English version of SHULCHAN ARUCH](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64243/english-version-of-shulchan-aruch)

Comment: Even though not an exact duplicate, but there is an answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64243/english-version-of-shulchan-aruch

Answer (score -1):

The Shulchan aruch harav that was printed (it seems not to include hilchos Talmud Torah, and halochos about Tefflin for now)
in english (with footnotes) is now available online at [chabad.org](http://chabad.org/3127874/)

---

The big Shulchan aruch is partially translated at [sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org/texts/Halakhah/Shulchan%20Arukh?lang=en)

Comment: `The big Shulchan aruch` Consider editing this, as this is not the common term for this work.

Comment: This really isnt an answer, since the OP obviously wants the classic work called Shulhan Arukh, not a lesser known work with a similar title. Furthermore, he wanted specifically, the _entire_ thing.